# Apply eslint-loader options in Vue-cli project so eslint configuration is respected

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, eslint, vue-cli, eslint-loader

My Vue-Cli project is based on the Vuexy template (not open source).

The problem I'm experiencing is eslint rules that I have disabled are breaking the build.

When I first run `vue-cli-service serve`, it builds and runs fine. Any change to source code, however, triggers linting, and rules which should be disabled are showing up as errors:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3:57:50 pm

 error  in ./src/views/inventory/map/layers/lotsData.js

Module Error (from .../node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

.../frontends/backoffice/src/views/inventory/map/layers/lotsData.js
  70:40  error  'map' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  87:3   error  Unexpected console statement     no-console

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

The `.eslintrc.js` looks like this:

```
const warnInLocal = process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined ? 0 : 'error'

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    'jest/globals': true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/recommended', '@vue/airbnb'],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['**/node_modules/**', '**/.history/**'],
  rules: {
    // These make sense in deployment, but cause friction in local development
    'no-console': 0,
    'no-debugger': 0,
    'no-unused-vars': 0,
    'no-unused-expressions': 0,
  },
  plugins: ['jest'],
}
```

vue.config.js:

```
//snipped
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/',
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@themeConfig': path.resolve(__dirname, 'themeConfig.js'),
        '@core': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@core'),
        '@validations': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@core/utils/validations/validations.js'),
        '@axios': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/libs/axios'),
      },
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        options.transformAssetUrls = {
            // snipped
        }
        return options
      })
  },
  transpileDependencies: ['vue-echarts', 'resize-detector'],
}
```

And finally package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.14.5",
    "@serverless-stack/cli": "0.36.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.9",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.9",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.9",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.9",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.3.0",
    "@vuepress/plugin-medium-zoom": "^1.7.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.14.0",
    "sass": "1.32.*",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.x"
  }
```

There are settings given in the [eslint-loader documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-loader) but they refer to a webpack configuration file which this project doesn't have. I think I'm somehow supposed to put them under `chainWebpack` but I don't really understand what that looks like.

(I also get that eslint-loader is deprecated, but I don't think I'm in a position to replace it.)

I'm really just trying to get the eslint configuration applying properly even during hot reloads, so any advice to get to that point is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to to my vue.config.js seems to work:

```js
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // ... existing 'vue-loader' rule ...

    // stop warnings breaking the build locally
    config.module
      .rule('eslint')
      .use('eslint-loader')
      .loader('eslint-loader')
      .tap(options => ({
        ...options,
        failOnWarning: false,
        failOnError: true,
        emitWarning: true,
      }))
```